# LINQ Map one type to another

Tags: linq, mapping, except

I need to find difference between to sets. Classes ,comprising the sets,  are different but have same type of fields. To be able to use Except method ,to take the difference, i want to map one list to another.

Can i do this using toList method? if not, Is it possible in another way?

```
List<Class1>.Except(List<Class2> I need to map class2 list to class1 list)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In LINQ, Select is synonymous with "map" in other languages.  It is called "select" because the word comes from database terminology... but Select is what you want:

`var mappedTypes = myCollection.Select(item => new MappedType(item.Something));`

Answer (score 1):

If you want a projection you can use ye olde [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) operator:

```
list1.Except(list2.Select(x => ConvertToClass1(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Class1>.Except(List<Class2>.Select(e => 
                                           new Class1() 
                                                    { 
                                                      Field1 = e.Field1 ...
                                                    });
```

However, I would advise you to use [automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).